# Implementing a custom agglomerative algorithm from scratch

Tags: java, algorithm, math, frameworks, cluster-analysis

I know about agglomerative clustering algorithms, the way it starts with each data point as individual clusters and then combines points to form clusters.

Now, I have a *n* dimensional space and several data points that have values across each of these dimensions. I want to cluster two points/clusters based on business rules like:

- Cluster two points c1 and c2 if the distance between the clusters across dimension 1 is < T1, and the distance across dimension 2 < T2, ... and distance across dimension n < Tn.
- If the rule across dimension 1 is met and rule across dimension 2 is met, then cluster them without bothering about the other dimensions...

.... and similar custom rules.

In addition, I have my own way of defining and measuring the distance between any two clusters in any particular dimension. The dimension may be holding just strings, and I want to define my own string distance metric. In another dimension, it may hold names of locations, and the distance between the two points along this dimension is the geographical distance between location named, and so on for other dimensions as well.

Is there a framework/software that lets me implement this way of defining custom distance metrics, and then to implement agglomerative clustering? Of course, the agglomerative clustering stops when the business rules are not met at any point of time, and we have clusters formed in the n dimensional space at the end.

Thanks
Abhishek S

Comment: I want to use JAVA, and preferably use a framework if it is available or me :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it with [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/).

You would have to implement a [Distance Function](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/DistanceFunction.html), and pass it to the [Hierarchical Clusterer](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/clusterers/HierarchicalClusterer.html) using the `setDistanceFunction(DistanceFunction distanceFunction)` method.

The other available clusterers in Weka are: Cobweb, EM, FarthestFirst, FilteredClusterer,  MakeDensityBasedClusterer, RandomizableClusterer, RandomizableDensityBasedClusterer, RandomizableSingleClustererEnhancer, SimpleKMeans, SingleClustererEnhancer.

An example distance function, from the [NormalizableDistance](https://svn.scms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/trunk/weka/src/main/java/weka/core/NormalizableDistance.java) class:

```
  /** Index in ranges for MIN. */
  public static final int R_MIN = 0;

  /** Index in ranges for MAX. */

  public static final int R_MAX = 1;

  /** Index in ranges for WIDTH. */
  public static final int R_WIDTH = 2;

  /** the instances used internally. */
  protected Instances m_Data = null;

  /** True if normalization is turned off (default false).*/
  protected boolean m_DontNormalize = false;

  /** The range of the attributes. */
  protected double[][] m_Ranges;

  /** The range of attributes to use for calculating the distance. */
  protected Range m_AttributeIndices = new Range("first-last");

  /** The boolean flags, whether an attribute will be used or not. */
  protected boolean[] m_ActiveIndices;

  /** Whether all the necessary preparations have been done. */
  protected boolean m_Validated;


public double distance(Instance first, Instance second, double cutOffValue, PerformanceStats stats) {
    double distance = 0;
    int firstI, secondI;
    int firstNumValues = first.numValues();
    int secondNumValues = second.numValues();
    int numAttributes = m_Data.numAttributes();
    int classIndex = m_Data.classIndex();

    validate();

    for (int p1 = 0, p2 = 0; p1 < firstNumValues || p2 < secondNumValues; ) {
      if (p1 >= firstNumValues)
        firstI = numAttributes;
      else
        firstI = first.index(p1); 

      if (p2 >= secondNumValues)
        secondI = numAttributes;
      else
        secondI = second.index(p2);

      if (firstI == classIndex) {
        p1++; 
        continue;
      }
      if ((firstI < numAttributes) && !m_ActiveIndices[firstI]) {
        p1++; 
        continue;
      }

      if (secondI == classIndex) {
        p2++; 
        continue;
      }
      if ((secondI < numAttributes) && !m_ActiveIndices[secondI]) {
        p2++;
        continue;
      }

      double diff;

      if (firstI == secondI) {
        diff = difference(firstI,
                  first.valueSparse(p1),
                  second.valueSparse(p2));
        p1++;
        p2++;
      }
      else if (firstI > secondI) {
        diff = difference(secondI, 
                  0, second.valueSparse(p2));
        p2++;
      }
      else {
        diff = difference(firstI, 
                  first.valueSparse(p1), 0);
        p1++;
      }
      if (stats != null)
        stats.incrCoordCount();

      distance = updateDistance(distance, diff);
      if (distance > cutOffValue)
        return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    }

    return distance;
  }
```

Shows that you can treat separately the various dimensions (that are called attributes in Weka). So you can define a different distance for each dimension/attribute.

About the business rules to avoid clustering together some instances. I think that you can create a distance function that returns `Double.positiveInfinity` when the business rules are not satisfied.

Comment: Can we set the distance function separately across various different dimensions? Also, can we write the business rules to cluster two points/clusters only if the business rules match?

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope that now it answers to all your questions :)

Comment: Thanks so much Vitalij. Is it possible for you to explain the code? I am unable to learn what few variables (such as m_Data, m_ActiveIndices) are because they are not declared in the method. Is there a reference tutorial somewhere you know that tells me what these variables are?

Comment: I have added the variables declarations and comments in the example. The best guide is http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code

Comment: Thanks! Do you now from where we can learn the complete WEKA architecture in detail? I want to understand the various classes and packages that exist and then program it accordingly.

Comment: Well the best referenceis the weka manual, this is the one for version 3.7.6: http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/weka/WekaManual-3-7-6.pdf?download

Comment: I implemented the distance function and returned Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY inside the distance function for any pair of instances that are matched. In this case, I see that the number of clusters that are found is 2. Why is it so?

Answer (score 2):

[ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) is another option. It has much more clustering algorithms than Weka (which is mostly useful for classification). They even have a Wiki Tutorial explaining how to implement custom distance functions (which you then should be able to use in hierarchical clustering):
[distance function tutorial](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/Tutorial/DistanceFunctions).

Note that "business rules" is not a very common way to specify a distance function...

Comment: I want to specify the business rules for the distances calculated across various dimensions. Do you know of a framework that lets me specify these business rules, and then the framework clusters two data points/clusters only if the business rule is matched?

Comment: Anony, do yo know where I can get to learn how to program using ELKI? It looks very interesting.

Comment: Did you try the tutorial link I posted? And no, I wouldn't ever touch business rules. They're called "business" crap for a reason.

Comment: yes, I understood how to mention a custom distance measure, but then I want to know how to plug that distancefunction inside a larger code that does clustering.

Comment: Try the GUI. It works for me. I configure the clustering algorithm there, and put my class name as distance function. The GUI is the easiest way to do all this, don't bother to do it all in Java.

Comment: ahh ok, let me try looking at the GUI now. Thanks!

Comment: @Anony-Mousse : I can't find agglomerative clustering algorithms in ELKI. Can you help me out here?

Comment: It currently on has SLINK, which is the efficient version O(n^2) instead of O(n^3) of single-link.
I figure they did not bother to implement the naive algorithm yet, because it does not scale. But it's also super simple to implement. Compute a distance matrix, choose two objects to merge, shrink the matrix, repeat.